# Setting up docker container on remote windows server VM

Tags: docker, windows-10, virtual-machine, git-bash, selenium-grid

I'm currently trying to set up a Selenium Grid in a docker container which will be hosted on a remote Windows Virtual machine. I have installed docker and I seem to be able to create a container that will run Selenium. But I have no idea how to make Docker use my windows VM as the host.

I have an IP address for the VM, but I cannot find a command that will allow me to specify where I want my grid hosted. Does anyone how to do this in docker?

I am using

- Windows 10
- Docker Desktop for Windows 10
- Mobaxterm to RDP into my Windows 10 VM
- Git bash to run docker commands